# File browse button hidden with multiple CMFCEditBrowseCtrl

Tags: c++, user-interface, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, mfc

I am having trouble using multiple CMFCEditBrowseCtrl controls in a dialog.  There is no problem with only one, but with two or more, the browse button is hidden.  If I try using the [EnableBrowseButton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb983421.aspx#cmfceditbrowsectrl__enablebrowsebutton) method, I get a generic browse button with ellipsis, as if it were a custom browse mode; clicking this does nothing.  If I try getting the browse mode with [GetMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb983421.aspx#cmfceditbrowsectrl__getmode), I find that it is set to None, even though I have explicitly set the browse mode property to File Browse.  What is causing this errant behavior?

Comment: The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb983421.aspx) has no mention of any limitations. A [mcve] would help. It should be *minimal* and *complete*.

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to have happen?

Comment: Did you actually read the documentation that you linked? To me it looks like `EnableBrowseButton` works as documented. Maybe you wanted to call `EnableFileBrowseButton` or `EnableFolderBrowseButton` instead?

Comment: I am aware the documentation has no mention of limitations.  (If it did I probably would not have a question.)  I will try to edit my answer with some more tangible information.

Answer (score 0):

```
CMFCEditBrowseCtrl::OnChangeLayout
```

Redraws the current edit browse control.

try to Use this function

https://github.com/Microsoft/cpp-docs/blob/master/docs/mfc/reference/cmfceditbrowsectrl-class.md